# Press other button2 when button 1 is pressed EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel, user-interface

I have 3 toggle buttons as shown in Excel VBA. First I press **continuous** then it will be pressed and start running macro. During that if I need to press **Emergency button** I need to do :

step1: Switch off Continuous button

step2 : Switch on Emergency Button
( **manual** is irrelevent here)
[image: Forget about manual button]

Currently when I try to do this, **Emergency Stop** cannot be pressed until macro of **continuous** ends.

Comment: Can I do this in visual basic in Visual studio and link Excel-vba code?

Comment: Yes it is possible.. One moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this most of the time when I trying to say, scrape data from the net.

```
Option Explicit

Dim boolStop As Boolean

'~~> Continuous button
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CommandButton1.Enabled = False

    boolStop = False

    For i = 1 To 1000000000
        For j = 1 To 1000000000
            Debug.Print i
            DoEvents

            If boolStop = True Then
                Msgbox "Operation Paused by the User"
                CommandButton1.Enabled = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub

'~~> Emergency button
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    boolStop = True
End Sub
```